# Convert Seconds to HH:MM:SS in teradata

Tags: time, teradata

I have a  decimal(6,2) field storing data in seconds.

I want those seconds to be converted in to **HH:MM:SS.**

For ex: **'19,500'** seconds should be shown as **05:25:00**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the datatype is a typo (you can't store 19500 in a decimal(6,2)):

```
col * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND    -- no fractional seconds

col * INTERVAL '00:00:01.00' HOUR TO SECOND -- fractional seconds
```