# compute columns in teradata from prevoius row and other columns

Tags: concatenation, teradata, lag

I have the below table format and wanted to compute the last column based on other two columns:

```
   BASE_VERSION JOURNEY_NO  LINE_NO DIRECTION   OP_DEP_NO   SEQ_NO  BLOCK_NO    DEP_TIME    TRAV_TIME   ARRV_TIME
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   1   21,760,010  5:25:00 ?   5:25:00
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   2   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:45 5:25:45
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   3   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:43 5:26:28
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   4   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:47 5:27:15
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   5   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:59 5:28:14
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   6   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:01:31 5:29:45
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   7   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:01:08 5:30:53
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   8   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:01:37 5:32:30
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   9   21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:48 5:33:18
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   10  21,760,010  5:25:00 0:01:02 5:34:20
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   11  21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:38 5:34:58
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   12  21,760,010  5:25:00 0:01:18 5:36:16
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   13  21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:58 5:37:14
20,160,603  33,263  176 1   2   14  21,760,010  5:25:00 0:00:47 5:38:01
```

Last Column ARRV_TIME for first row is (DEP_TIME + TRAV_TIME) . from second row ARRV_TIME is calculated as prev value + current row TRAV_TIME.

eg: 1 row for ARRV_TIME is (5:25:00 +?) = 5:25:00. from 2 row to rest is calculated as prev result which is 5:25:00 + 0:00:45 = 5:25:45 then next row is 5:25:45 + 0:00:43 = 5:26:28 and so on for each LINE_NO and DIRECTION.

Comment: What's the datatype of those columns? How is the order determined?

Comment: @dnoeth The data types are decimal. The Order can be determined through a seq. missed seq. column in the question.Now updated the dataset with seq. column

Comment: So you're looking for a running sum, basically?  What column(s) make up the key, if you will? Additionally, the datatype of `DEP_TIME` and `TRAV_TIME` are decimal? Those look like times to me...

Comment: What's the actual data stored for `5:25:00` and `0:01:31`, `52500` AND `131`? Why it's decimal instead of TIME and INTERVAL? Or is it the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521268/convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-in-teradata?

Comment: @dnoeth its same as you mentioned. DEP_TIME and TRAV_TIME are derived columns 'col * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND' .

Comment: @Andrew LINE_NO, DIRECTION, SEQ_NO is the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You describe a Cumulative Sum, one of the basic tasks for an Analytic Function:

```
SUM(column TRAV_TIME is based on) 
OVER (PARTITION BY LINE_NO, DIRECTION
      ORDER BY SEQ_NO
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

Add this to the column `DEP_TIME` is based on and then apply the interval calculation

```
result * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND
```

This results in an Interval, if you need a Time datatype:

```
TIME '00:00:00' + (result * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND)
```